# Doctrine 2 - ManyToMany relationship - empty collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have many to many relationship between user and groups, but when I want to access all groups for user I get empty collection.

```
namespace LoginBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $_iId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="login", length=45)
     */
    private $_sLogin;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="GroupBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy="_aUser")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Group_x_User",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $_aGroup;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_aGroup = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get iId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_iId;
    }

    /**
     * Set sLogin
     *
     * @param string $sLogin
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLogin($sLogin)
    {
        $this->_sLogin = $sLogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sLogin
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return $this->_sLogin;
    }

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->_aGroup;
    }
```

User and Group use Group_x_User table to store their relationships.

```
namespace GroupBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Group")
 */
class Group
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $_iId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=45)
     */
    private $_sName;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LoginBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="_aGroup")
     */
    private $_aUser;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_aUser = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get iId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_iId;
    }

    /**
     * Set sName
     *
     * @param string $sName
     *
     * @return Group
     */
    public function setName($sName)
    {
        $this->_sName = $sName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_sName;
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->_aUser;
    }
}
```

For restoring data from database I use code:

```
$oUser = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('LoginBundle:User')
        ->find(2);
$aGroup = $oUser->getGroups();
```

Unfortunatelly $aGroup collection contains array of 0 elements while in database are records which are matching. What am I missing in my mapping?

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing from your `User` class. You only declare `_aGroup` with `ArrayCollection`. This is not enough. You have to store the data into `ArrayCollection`.

Add this into `User` class.

```
public class addGroups(\GroupBundle\Entity\Group $group)
{
    $group->addUsers($this);
    $this->_aGroup->add($group);
}
```

This is for `Group` class.

```
public class addUsers(\LoginBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    if (!$this->_aUser->contains($user)) {
        $this->_aUser->add($user);
    }
}
```

For more information, you can visit this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: Probably you meant public function. I have added this functions to both classes but still collection is empty.

Answer (score 0):

@ORM\JoinTable() annotation syntax on User::$_aGroup definition is intended to be used for self-referencing relations [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing).

Try using simplified syntax :

```
@JoinTable(name="Group_x_User")
```

If you use common conventions ('id' as column name for identifiers, and so on) Doctrine and Symfony will do the rest for you.